# How to *reliably* install the VC++ redistributable on end-user computers

Tags: visual-c++, redistributable, vcredist

Best practices from Microsoft dictate that we link dynamically to the VC++ runtime for security reasons, and it sure would be nice if our application automatically picked up hotfixes without requiring a separate application update from our side.

However, over the past couple of years, I've been making installers for the [Evolve](https://www.evolvehq.com) client. Our single biggest issue with installing the client has been caused by failed vcredist installations. The biggest error codes being:

- 1612: The installation source for this product is not available. Verify that the source exists and that you can access it.
- 1638: Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.

We've also [run in to cases](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0a2608a-3102-40f8-93ce-253d08d91406/32bit-version-of-msvcr100dll-is-installed-in-64bit-cwindowssystem32-directory) where some third-party application had manually installed the 32-bit version of msvcr100.dll in System32 on a 64-bit version of Windows, obviously causing all applications on the system relying on this to fail.

**Now, my question is this:** If a developer wants to follow Microsoft's guidelines for the good of the land, how are we to succeed if our products can't reliably be installed? I'm at a crossroads right now where I only see two options going forward:

1. Link all my binaries statically to the runtime and take the hit on binary size and the security implications associated with it.
2. Manually distribute the VC++ runtime DLLs and dump them in my application's folder although I don't even know if I'm allowed to do that.

What is everybody else doing out there?

Comment: For VS 2010 or later, you can use the application local solution. For VS 2005/2008, this was not an option. The preferred method is to launch the VCREDIST*.EXE with admin rights at install time. Note that you may be hitting a bug that was specifically in the VS 2010 RTM version of the VCREDIST*.EXE. See [KB2728613](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2728613) and [KB2717426](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426).

Comment: Note that if you have a 3rd party application install the 32-bit version of the DLL into the System32 directory of a 64-bit OS, that installer is basically broken and is not compatible with the 64-bit OS.